# How to get current provider of session in Next-auth

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

In Next-auth, We can get session related info like user: {name, email .. etc}

something as follows:

```
import { useSession } from "next-auth/client"

export default function Component() {
  const [session, loading] = useSession()

  if (session) {
    return <p>Signed in as {session.user.email}</p>
  }

  return <a href="/api/auth/signin">Sign in</a>
}
```

I want to get also the current provider name in my component to be used. For you your information, next-auth supports login by many providers as Facebook, Twitter .. etc

For example, if the user logged in via Twitter Api, I want to get this piece of info and print it in his profile page.

Sources:
https://next-auth.js.org/v3/getting-started/client#usesession

Answer (score 5):

`Callbacks` can be used for passing additional data to `session` object.

`Provider` details are provided the first time user signs in.

You can use `jwt` callback to store data in `jwt` cookie.

In [...nextauth].js :

```
const callbacks = {}

callbacks.jwt = async function jwt(token, user , account) {
    
    if (user) {
        token = { id: user.id  , provider:account.provider , ...moreData}
    }

    return token
}

const options = {
    providers,
    callbacks
}
```

**Note**: You also need to use `session` callback for passing the `token` data to `useSession` hook.

```
callbacks.session = async function session(session, token) {
    session.user = {
        provider : token.provider,
        id: dbUser.id,
        profile: dbUser.profile,
        
    }

    return session
}

export default (req, res) => NextAuth(req, res, options)
```

This way provider will be stored in the token for subsequent requests.

Learn more about callbacks here : [Callbacks](https://next-auth.js.org/v3/configuration/callbacks)

Comment: This leads me to the correct path, but needs some modification. Since the account return only id and type properties, it could be something like: `if (user) {
    
    token.provider = account?.id ;
    token.user = user.data.user; // add any data you want to recieve in the session
   }`