# Need to differentiate login callback credentials from google and facebook using next-auth

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am getting data successfully from google and facebook login using next-auth. I want to save separate profiles for Google and Facebook as well. Data I am getting is name, image, email and session expiry but I need to differentiate the callback data. Maybe a provider name would work. I have tried to add provider in session and use it in page but in vain

**Here is code for pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js**

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";

export default NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
        clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        authorization: {
            params: {
              prompt: "consent",
              access_type: "offline",
              response_type: "code"
            }
        }
    }),
    FacebookProvider({
      clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET
    })
  ],
  jwt: {
    encryption: true
  },
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  callback: {
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      // Persist the OAuth access_token to the token right after signin
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
      }
      if (account?.provider) {
        token.provider = account.provider;
      }
      return Promise.resolve(token);
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      // Send properties to the client, like an access_token from a provider.
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      session.provider = token.provider;
      return Promise.resolve(session);
    },
    // redirect: async(url, _baseUrl) => {
    //     if (url === "/profile") {
    //         return Promise.resolve("/");
    //     }
    //     return Promise.resolve("/");
    // }
  }
})
```

Here is code for login page

```
const {data:session} = useSession();
{JSON.stringify(session, 4)};
```

Result I get is

```
{"user":{"name":"myname","email":"myemail","image":"myimage"},"expires":"2022-09-04T16:40:10.809Z"};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get current provider of session in Next-auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69155653/how-to-get-current-provider-of-session-in-next-auth)

Comment: @rokob Whatever I add to token and session it only returns the name, email, image, expiry

Comment: Now even I have no code in session and jwt callback, still it is returning the same data